# Split a string into 2 variables in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string with the following format: `city (Country)` and I would like to separate the *city* and the *country* and store the values in 2 different variables.

I tried the following and it is working to store the city but not for the country.

```
<?php

$citysearch = "Madrid (Spain)";
echo $citysearch;

$citylen = strlen( $citysearch );
for( $i = 0; $i <= $citylen; $i++ )
{
  $char = substr( $citysearch, $i, 1 );
  if ($char <> "(")
  {
    echo $city. "<br>"; 
    $city = $city .$char;
    if ($char == " ")
    {
      break;
    } 
  }
  if ($char <> ")")
  {
    echo $country. "<br>"; 
    $country = $country .$char;
    if ($char == ")")
    {
      break;
    } 
  }
}

echo "This is the city:" .$city;
echo "This is the country:" . $country;;

?>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If it's always in the same format, have a look at [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match).

Comment: @SamueldelRio, your answer is ready. [Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167965/split-a-string-into-2-variables-in-php/37168130#37168130)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple regex to solve this:

```
preg_match('/^(\w*)\s\((\w*)\)$/', $citysearch, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
echo "city: ".$matches[1]."\n";
echo "country: ".$matches[2]."\n";
```

**Update:**
Or without regex:

```
$citysearch = 'Madrid (Spain)';
$pos = strpos($citysearch, ' (');
$city = substr($citysearch, 0, $pos);
$country = substr($citysearch, $pos + 2, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `explode` in php :

```
<?php
$citysearch = "Madrid (Spain)";
$myArray = explode('(', $citysearch);
print($myArray[0]);
print(rtrim($myArray[1], ")"));
?>
```

Using `preg_split`:

```
<?php
$citysearch = "Madrid (Spain)";
$iparr = preg_split ("/\(/", rtrim($citysearch, ")"));
print($iparr[0]);
print($iparr[1]);
?>
```

Output:

```
Madrid Spain
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with this simple example:

Just explode the string with `explode` function, then store the city in the `$city` variable and store the country in `$country` variable.

After exploding the string you will get an array, where in index 0 is the value `Madrid` and index 1 is `(Spain)`. So its easy to get the city using `$div[0]`, but for country you need to use a spacial function called `trim` for clearing the `()`. and use `$div[1]` to get the country.

**Example:**

```
$citysearch = "Madrid (Spain)";
$div = explode(" ", $citysearch);

echo $city = $div[0]; //Madrid
echo $country = trim($div[1], "()"); //Spain
```

Answer (score 0):

using explode

```
$citysearch = "Madrid (Spain)";
$ar =explode("(",$citysearch,2);
$ar[1]=rtrim($ar[1],")");
$city = $ar[0];
$country = $ar[1];
```